# $R^n \cong R^m$ if and only if $n=m$ without assuming the result for vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

Given two free modules $R^n$ and $R^m$ over a commutative ring $R$, it's true that $R^n \cong R^m$ if and only if $n=m$. However every proof I've seen of this fact assumes that we've first proven it when $R$ is a field. Although this is probably true (most of us see linear algebra before commutative algebra), this sort of proof is a bit unsatisfactory to me.

Is there a (nice) proof of $R^n \cong R^m$ if and only if $n=m$ that doesn't assume we know it's true when $R$ is a field?

$\bf{Edit}$ Though the linked question implies a proof that does not use the result for $R$ a field, such an implication doesn't mean that the questions are duplicates of one another.

Comment: This requires that $R$ is finitely generated, right? Like if I take $R$ to be the free commutative ring generated by a $a_0, a_1, \dots$, then $R \cong R^2$. I think. My algebra is very rusty :P

Comment: @AlexMeiburg I'm pretty sure the ring would have to be non-commutative for something weird like that to happen, otherwise I'm ridiculously lost

Comment: @AlexMeiburg $R\cong R^2$ as rings but not as $R$-modules.